BroadcastReceiver doesn't receive intent if registered in code, but if in manifest it's do
I faced with problem that my receiver just doesn't works if I registering it in my activity, but if I register it in manifest, it works good.
This receiver needs to handle an intent that sends after button clicked in notification.
For testing it I created new simple project.
In manifest I added permission for notification:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
In Activity we just create an notification right away, here is full code of activity:
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val receiver = CancelNotificationReceiver()

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val filter = IntentFilter(CancelNotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION_CANCEL_ACTION)
        ContextCompat.registerReceiver(
            this,
            receiver,
            filter,
            ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED
        )

        val channelIdStr = "channel"

        val closeIntent = Intent(this, CancelNotificationReceiver::class.java).apply {
            action = CancelNotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION_CANCEL_ACTION
        }
        val closePendingIntent: PendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 0, closeIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
            )

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelIdStr)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Text")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .addAction(
                0, "Close",
                closePendingIntent
            )

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelIdStr, "channelName", importance).apply {
                description = "channelDescription"
            }
            val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).apply {
            notify(1, builder.build())
        }
    }
}

And here is receiver:
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.widget.Toast

class CancelNotificationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    companion object {
        const val NOTIFICATION_CANCEL_ACTION = "NOTIFICATION_CANCEL_ACTION"
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        when (intent.action) {
            NOTIFICATION_CANCEL_ACTION -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}

So if user clicks button in notification, toast with text "canceled" need to be shown, but it's not.
But when I register my receiver in manifest like that, it starts working:
<receiver android:name=".CancelNotificationReceiver"/>
But I wan't to register receivers in my code, not in manifest.
I read https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/build-notification and https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks/broadcasts documentation but don't understand what did wrong.

Ok, I found out a solution
Instead of this:
val closeIntent = Intent(this, CancelNotificationReceiver::class.java).apply {
    action = CancelNotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION_CANCEL_ACTION
}

Just need to do this:
val closeIntent = Intent().apply {
    action = CancelNotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION_CANCEL_ACTION
}

and now its working
